# How to get Wormwood on Phoenix Reborn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am playing the Phoenix Reborn modpack and run into troubles creating wormwood (from witchery). The problem is, I think, the combination with agricraft, which makes it such that:

1) Wheat can't be planted on Farmland (but on Fertilized dirt)
2) On right click, the wheat is harvested; this interferes with the requirement to right-click the fully grown wheat with the mutating sprig.

Problem 1 is solved by using fertilized dirt (although I think that's not intended). Is there a way around problem 2?